# Run setblock command in Minecraft to change villager into pig

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to use `/setblock` or another command to convert a villager into a pig, similar to how you can use `/setblock` to change one block to another?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to directly convert an entity into a different entity. The best workaround is to summon a pig at the villager and kill the villager.

Like so:

```
execute as @e[type=villager,tag=villager1] at @s run function namespace:convert_to_pig
```

function `convert_to_pig`:

```
summon pig ~ ~ ~
 
tp @s ~ -500 ~
kill @s
```